# How can I check a Content Control under VS2008 + .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I've been trying to access the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ContentControl.Checked method, however it's not being recognised, and it's leading me to believe it's not supported under VS2008 & .NET 3.5.

Is there any way I can get around this (and no, moving to a newer version of VS2008 & .NET 3.5 isn't an option for me)?

Comment: Please include the code you're using and specify the version of Word involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll installed as part of the Visual Studio Tools for Office I was using in visual Studio 2008 (v12/Office 2007) it appears does not support CheckBox Content controls. Installing VS2010 (which adds support for v14/Office 2010 of the tools) does.

Thankfully I can just import the v14 DLL into vs2008 with no issues, and in order to access the 'checked' property of a contentcontrol, I can now do:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ContentControl cc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ContentControl;
cc.Checked = true;
```